# In jsTree, what's the best way to make the node text clickable (for checking the checkbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

When clicking on the text of a node beside the checkbox, I'd like for the checkbox to toggle its checked state. Ordinarily this is done with a `<label for="whatever"></label>`. But since **jsTree** doesn't use real checkboxes, how might this be done?

When creating the tree with `$('#mytree').jstree({'plugins':['checkbox']})`, if I put `.delegate("a", "click", function (event, data) { $(event.target).find('.jstree-checkbox').click() })` at the end, it works. But there is a discernible delay.

Hence, I pose the question, what is the best way to check the box when clicking its corresponding text?

Comment: You've mentioned that JsTree does not use real checkboxes - but that's only the default behaviour. Did you know that you can configure the Checkbox plugin to use real checkboxes? (see http://www.jstree.com/documentation/checkbox)

Comment: Yes, but it still doesn't work with that option. Anyway, by "use real checkboxes", I meant it doesn't allow you to build a ul/li tree with checkboxes and labels, which would have been a nice way to allow for label clicking.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the click handler technique you're using. I don't see the delay mentioned, but that could be because I'm not posting anything back to the server.

If the checkbox is purely visual, then perhaps the class can be modified directly. This should be must faster than throwing another click event.

```
$(event.target).parent("li:first").toggleClass("jstree-unchecked").toggleClass("jstree-checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox plugin for jstree does appear to perform other actions when checking / unchecking the node. I believe the following should do what you're looking for:

```
$(function(){
    // Initialize jstree
    var $tree = $('.tree-target').jstree({
        "plugins": ["checkbox"]
    });

    // Bind an event to the anchor tag within each tree entry
    // Note: '.on' is used here as this will ensure that any
    // dynamically-generated entries will also use this 'click'
    // event.
    $tree.on('click', 'li.tree > a', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        // Find the first parent 'tree' element
        var $node = $(this).parents('li.tree').eq(0);

        // Toggle the state of the current 'tree' element
        // Note: The third parameter (in this case 'toggle')
        // can be any value other than true or false
        $tree.jstree('change_state', $node, 'toggle');
        return false;
    });
});​
```

On a side note, I believe the reason your approach led to a significant delay could have to do with you binding the `click` event to every single `<a/>` tag on the page. This would result in significant overhead when trying to find the appropriate event targets.